# Django Views Get POST Data

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a hidden form in the Dajngo (1.10) template and would like to pass data to views.py. I followed the usual way however the result of getting data is nothing. Could you advise what has gone wrong and how to fix it? Many thanks. The code is as below for reference:

template:

```
        <form style="display: hidden" action="/exRpt/" method="POST" id="#form99">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" id="var199" name="var199" value=""/>
          <input type="hidden" id="var299" name="var299" value=""/>
        </form> 
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '.exWord', function(){  
            $("#var199").val("ExWord");
            $("#var299").val("1,4,10"); 


            $("#form99").submit();
            window.location.href = "/exRpt/"
        });
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def exRpt(request):
    in_type = request.POST.get('var199')
    in_news = request.POST.get('var299')
    ...
    response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.ms-word')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=SelectedNewsReport.docx'
    return response
```

Comment: I think your script is not being executed in that code, so the form is not getting those values.

Comment: You should not include the `#` in the form's id: `<form style="display: hidden" action="/exRpt/" method="POST" id="form99">`

Comment: @Alasdair is right. Your JS code isn't selecting the form, so you're not posting to the view. It's a get request (from your `window.location.href` statement, which you shouldn't need if the submit is working correctly). To confirm you can print out `request.method` in your view function. Update the ID as @alasdair mentioned and it should work correctly.

Comment: please dont use hardcoded urls in templates, use `{% url %}` tag instead

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Yes, stupid me. I should not put # in the form id! Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

it will be `same input` with same detail you should `chang` `one` of them and then with `javascript` set val.